# unit of scipy fft function

Tags: scipy, fft

I have a small confusion on units of FT. I’m looking at the first graph of (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/fft.html) and its corresponding code above the figure. I got that x-axis refers to frequency and y-axis refers to amplitudes. What would be the unit of x-axis though?

I know it should be related to the unit of `x (=np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N, endpoint=False))`. So for example, suppose the unit of x is a second (s). Then what would be the unit of xf?

Comment: If your time axis goes from 0 to T second (not included), then the frequency axis has steps of 1/T Hz. Both have N steps, so one step in time domain is T/N, and the frequency domain goes up to N/T (not included). Usually only half the frequency domain is plotted, because N/2T is the Nyquist frequency. (Your code has time domain up to NT, so adjust accordingly.)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think I got it. The X-axis of the graph is just a number without any unit, for instance of 50 and 80 in that example. Then, if x is in unit of seconds, then we can infer that the function's frequencies are 50 Hz and 80 Hz.